# How to add an email address in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

How can I add an email address to Thunderbird?

I have tried Tools → Account Settings → Account Actions → "Add mail account", but I get this error after entering my email information:

> Error Creating Account - Incoming Server Already Exists

At the moment all I have is "Local Folders" as an account with the SMTP setup to my hosting account. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you previously have an account made using this same name? Some sort of conflict with the stuff that is saved to disk?  Try Using manuel configuring, and change the Case (upper case lower case) on the newly created account.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about the upper/lower case change, but I did try to change the domain from mail.my_domain.com to my_domain.com and nothing. I seriously can not add an email account. I also just uninstalled and re-installed Thunderbird. I think I'm going to have to delete files.

Comment: Hi everybody, I have the answer to my question. However, I am finding Stack Overflow and Superuser to be difficult to use. I spent the time to write out a detailed answer only to have it declined. So I think I will quit complaining now and just move along.

Comment: @Mark - can you have another crack at an answer. There are plenty of people with this problem, myself included. It would be worth having your solution on here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an additional address to an existing account, you can do that in the "Manage Identities" dialog.

Relevant reading: [Multiple identities per e-mail account](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Suite_:_FAQs_:_Mail_Aliases)

Comment: Hi, I went to the link and it said goto Account Settings, choose the account and click "Manage Identities..." I don't seem to have that button? The only account I have is the local folders.